# Debug: how to fix this "missing delimiter" error

Tags: tables, delimiters, debugging

I am using an example-code for my CV. The code here is really simple, I acctually didn't use any "\left", but still getting this error of **"missing \right**", along with the error **"missing delimiter"** and **"missing $"**.

I am getting confused about the errors, since the example itself didn't provide any example to fix them. Could someone help me deal with these errors?

here is the position of these errors:

```
    % Sprach
    \cvitem{
    \cvheadingstyle{Sprachen}
}{
    \begin{left}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{p{4cm} p{4cm}} 
     Chinesisch & Muttersprache \\ 
     Deutsch & sehr gut \\
     Englisch & sehr gut \\
     Japanisch & grundlegend
    \end{tabular}
    \end{left}
}
```

Despite the errors, the code was successfully compiled and produced the following image, which is indeed what I wanted.

[image: the result]

here is the definition of the new commands used above:

```
% creates a standard, multi-purpose CV item with the given left and right column contents, parskip set to cvparskip
% in the right column, and with appropriate vertical space after
% @param #1 left column content
% @param #2 right column content
\newcommand{\cvitem}[2]{
    % left and right column
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvleftcolumnwidth}
        \raggedleft #1
    \end{minipage}% XXX necessary comment to avoid unwanted space
    \hspace{\cvcolumngapwidth}% XXX necessary comment to avoid unwanted space
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvrightcolumnwidth}
        \setlength{\parskip}{\cvparskip} #2
    \end{minipage}

    % space after
    \vspace{\cvafteritemskipamount}
}
```

about the command "cvheadline" (i think it is irrelevant)

```
% styles
\newcommand{\cvnamestyle}[1]{{\Large\cvnamefont\textcolor{cvnamecolor}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\cvsectionstyle}[1]{{\normalsize\cvsectionfont\textcolor{cvsectioncolor}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\cvtitlestyle}[1]{{\large\cvtitlefont\textcolor{cvtitlecolor}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\cvdurationstyle}[1]{{\small\cvdurationfont\textcolor{cvdurationcolor}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\cvheadingstyle}[1]{{\normalsize\cvheadingfont\textcolor{cvheadingcolor}{#1}}}
```

Thank you all! I felt so welcomed in this active community!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\begin{left}`...`\end{left}` is essentially the same as `\left`...`\endleft`, so you _are_ using `\left`. I think you want `\begin{flushleft}`...`\end{flushleft}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik "great minds think alike", or something:-)

Comment: Amazing! It works! ALL Errors gone! Thanks a lot, I am going to search about the flushleft :)

Answer (score 4):

`\begin{left}` executes `\left`.

I would guess that you intended `\begin{flushleft}`