# Recursion with counters not resetting counters

Tags: counters, expansion, recursion

I'm trying to use recursion to draw Sierpinski's triangle in TikZ. I have something that's partially working, but not quite. At each step, I draw something. Then, if the counter is positive, I call my macro again.

Here's a somewhat simplified example without the TikZ stuff (as I'm fairly certain that's not where my issue is):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
  \setcounter{mycounter}{#1}%
  \themycounter%
  \ifnum\themycounter>0%
    [%
    \setcounter{mycounter}{#1}%
    \addtocounter{mycounter}{-1}%
    \example\themycounter%
    ,%
    \setcounter{mycounter}{#1}%
    \addtocounter{mycounter}{-1}%
    \example\themycounter%
    ]%
  \fi%
}
    
\begin{document}

\example4

\end{document}
```

This is outputting:

```
4[3[2[1[0,-1],-2],-3],3[2[1[0,-1],-2],-3]]
```

What I want the output to be is:

```
4[3[2[1[0,0],1[0,0]],2[1[0,0],1[0,0]]],3[2[1[0,0],1[0,0]],2[1[0,0],1[0,0]]]]
```

I think my issue is that `\setcounter{mycounter}{#1}` is expanding to `\setcounter{mycounter}{\themycounter}`, which is resulting in no change to the value of `mycounter`, rather than resetting it to what it was at the start of the macro. Is there an easy solution to this? Do I need to learn how `\expandafter` works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the counters are the problem, remove the counters! :)

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\sierpinski#1{\number\expandafter\sierpaux\number\numexpr#1;}
\def\sierpaux#1;{%
  \ifnum#1=0 0%
  \else
    \expandafter\sierpauxi\number
      \expandafter\sierpaux\number\numexpr#1-1;;#1%
  \fi}
\def\sierpauxi#1;#2\fi{\fi#2[#1,#1]}

\begin{document}

\sierpinski4

\edef\x{\sierpinski{19}}

\end{document}
```

The code is a simple recursion of the `\sierpaux` macro.  When the loop starts, it traverses down the numbers, subtracting one, until it finds a zero, at which point the input stream looks like this:

```
\number\expandafter\sierpauxi
\number\expandafter\sierpauxi
\number\expandafter\sierpauxi
\number\expandafter\sierpauxi 0;1\fi;2\fi;3\fi;4\fi
```

then the last `\sierpauxi` kicks in and replaces `0;1\fi` by `\fi1[0,0]`, and then the `\fi` is expanded away and you have:

```
\number\expandafter\sierpauxi
\number\expandafter\sierpauxi
\number\expandafter\sierpauxi 1[0,0];2\fi;3\fi;4\fi
```

then again, `\sierpauxi` kicks in and replaces `1[0,0];2\fi` by `2[1[0,0],1[0,0]]`, rinse and repeat until you are left with the output.  Note that it just computed the list of numbers once, then used macro expansion to duplicate everything as needed, so this is O(n).

But the list grows big rather quickly, so the maximum number you can have in the argument is 19.

Here's a *much* slower version that allows up to 20:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\sierpinski#1{\sierpauxi{#1}}
\def\sierpauxi#1{\expandafter\sierpaux\number\numexpr#1;}
\def\sierpaux#1;{%
  \ifnum#1=0 0%
  \else #1\expandafter\sierpauxii\romannumeral-`0\sierpauxi{#1-1};%
  \fi}
\def\sierpauxii#1;{[#1,#1]}

\begin{document}

\sierpinski4

\edef\x{\sierpinski{20}}

\end{document}
```

This version evaluates both sides of the tree recursively, so it is O(n^2), but it does some more shuffling around that allows you to have a larger input.

Comment: hmm you were a few seconds faster:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503973/debug-how-to-fix-this-missing-delimiter-error#comment1273027_503973 :)

Comment: Without really understanding how either of your solutions works…it looks like the main difference is `\number` vs. `\expandafter{\the…\relax}`. Is the former a shorthand for the latter? I certainly support avoiding global variables, and I had only been using counters because I didn't realize TeX had something like this to use instead.

Comment: @PiFisher No, `\number` tells TeX to scan for a number, and `\the` tells it to expand the value of a register, but that's not the difference.  The first code is faster because it evaluates only one branch of the tree and duplicates it, but it takes a bit more memory to do so, thus it only allows up to 19.  The second version evaluates every branch, so it's much slower, but takes less memory, so you can go up to 20 without getting an error.

Comment: @PiFisher I added some explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Your explanation is correct but I think it is simpler not to use counters here especially latex counters which are global, and also use of `\themycounter` which is the print form and not guaranteed to be suitable for numeric tests.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
  \the\numexpr#1\relax
  \ifnum#1>0 %
    [%
    \expandafter\example\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
    ,%
    \expandafter\example\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
   ]%
  \fi%
}
    
\begin{document}

\example4

\end{document}
```

this just passes the value directly in `#1` without using a register